# Tree-sitter, how to use a "catch all" rule correctly?

Tags: treesitter

I have a grammar like this:

```js
terminator = '\n';

module.exports = grammar({
  name: 'sciname',

  rules: {
    source_file: ($) => repeat($._sci_name),

    _sci_name: ($) => seq($.uninomial, optional($.tail), terminator),

    _uninomial: ($) => /[A-Z][a-z]+/,

    uninomial: ($) => choice($._uninomial, seq($.genus, $.subgenus)),

    genus: ($) => $._uninomial,

    subgenus: ($) => seq('(', $._uninomial, ')'),

    tail: ($) => /.+/,
  },
});
```

`tail` rule suppose to catch anything that comes after `uninomial`. However I have trouble with this test:

```
=====================
Subgenus
=====================

Bubo (Bubo)

---------------------

(source_file (uninomial (genus) (subgenus)))
```

producing:

`(source_file (uninomial) (tail))`

instead of

`(source_file (uninomial (genus) (subgenus)))`

Changing precedence does not seem to influence this behavior. Is there a way to make a "catch-all" rule like `tail` to engage only if all other previous rules failed?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter/discussions/1407

[ahlinc](https://github.com/ahlinc) writes:

Try to assign a lower lexer precedence to your tail with a token(prec(-1, ...)) construct like:

```
tail: ($) => token(prec(-1, /[^\s]+/)),
```